ChatOpenAI: TypeError: 'FieldInfo' object is not a mapping
I have been experimenting with various langChain tutorials.  Every time I call the invoke(messages) function, I get the error message TypeError: 'FieldInfo' object is not a mapping.  I have gone through the langchain documentation and cannot see why this would be happening.  Seems to be happening in the in_default_params part of the chat_models base.
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model="gpt-4o",
    temperature=0,
    
)
messages = [
    (
        "system",
        "You are a helpful assistant that translates English to French. Translate the user sentence.",
    ),
    ("human", "I love programming."),
]
ai_msg = llm.invoke(messages)
ai_msg


I solved this.  It involved reinstalling the following using pip:
langchain
openai
langchain-openai
langchain-community and
Langchainhub
